# How to add a new entity to a domain context and immediately see it in data bound controls before SubmitChanges?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I've got a Silverlight 4 RIA Services (SP1) app using Entity Frameworks 4 CTP5. I can databind a grid or listbox to the IEnumerable loaded by the domain context and it shows data from the server.  Great.

Now I want to create a new instance of MyEntity and add it to the client-side data so that the user can see the newly added entity.  MyEntity is a true entity descendant, not a POCO.

The only Add method I can find is `domainContext.EntityContainer.GetEntitySet<MyEntity>().Add(newobj)`

This does add the new entity to the domain context, and the domainContext.HasChanges does become true, but the new entity doesn't show up in the databound controls.

How do I get the new entity to show up in the databound controls prior to SubmitChanges?

(Probably related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423840/programmatically-add-row-to-entity-data-model-context-and-have-new-row-show-up-in) SO question from years ago that never got an answer)

Here's the server side declarations of the domain service, per requests:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class MyDomainService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<MyObjectContext>
{
    protected override MyObjectContext CreateObjectContext()
    {
        return new MyObjectContext();
    }

    public IQueryable<MyEntity> GetMyEntities()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.MyEntities;
    }

    public void InsertMyEntity(MyEntity MyEntity)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void UpdateMyEntity(MyEntity currentMyEntity)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void DeleteMyEntity(MyEntity MyEntity)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out with a combination of my own trial and error and hints provided by some of the other responses to this question.

The key point I was missing was that it's not enough for the ViewModel to keep track of the DomainContext and hand out query results to the View for databinding.  The ViewModel also has to capture and retain the query results if you want entity adds and deletes performed by the ViewModel to appear in the UI before DomainContext.SubmitChanges().  The ViewModel has to apply those adds to the collection view of the query results.

The ViewModel collection property for View databinding.  In this case I'm using the Telerik **QueryableDomainServiceCollectionView**, but other collection views can be used:

```
    public IEnumerable<MyEntity> MyEntities
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.view == null)
            {
                DomainContextNeeded();
            }
            return this.view;
        }
    }

    private void DomainContextNeeded()
    {
        this.context = new MyDomainContext();
        var q = context.GetMyEntitiesQuery();
        this.view = new Telerik.Windows.Data.QueryableDomainServiceCollectionView<MyEntity>(context, q);
        this.view.Load();
    }
```

The ViewModel function that adds a new entity for the UI to display:

```
public void AddNewMyEntity(object selectedNode)
{
    var ent = new MyEntity() { DisplayName = "New Entity" };

    if (selectedNode == null)
    {
        this.view.AddNew(ent);
    }
    else if (selectedNode is MyEntity)
    {
        ((MyEntity)selectedNode).Children.Add(ent);
    }
}
```

Other responses mentioned ObservableCollection.  The query results and the collection view may not return instances of ObservableCollection.  They could be just IEnumerables.  What is critical is that they implement INotifyCollectionChanged and **IEditableCollectionView**.

Thanks to those who contributed responses.  I've +1'd each response that was helpful, but since none directly solved my problem I couldn't justify marking any as the definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your domainContext will have a property domainContext.MyEntities. Does it not show up in there when you add it?

Bind to that collection or watch that collection for changes.

domainContext.MyEntities.PropertyChanged += MyEventHandler;

Comment: The RIA generated domain context does not have a MyEntities collection.  It has a GetMyEntitiesQuery function generated to make the WCF call back to the server.

Comment: Ahh, how do you get the items from the server? Is it a [Query] method or an Invoke that returns the object tree? I've just realised you might not have that the collection property if you don't have a query method for that entity type. We have some empty query methods that aren't actually implemented to get the generated code.

Comment: I'm using the query method.  var q = context.GetMyEntitiesQuery(); var op = context.Load(q); control.ItemsSource = op.Entities;

Comment: Edit the question with the signature of your server side method, with attributes. The actual implementation doesn't really matter so much.

Comment: Hmm, all our services have a [Query][Insert][Update][Delete] attribute on them but maybe we don't need them and they can be inferred or convention based. I'll have to wait until I get back to work on Monday to give you a code sample. Sorry

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, DataContext.SubmitChanges() works fine.  It does send the added entity to the server.  The part that isn't working is how/where to add the new entity on the client side so that databound controls will show it.

Comment: Add the new entity directly to the ObservableCollection in your view model which your view is bound to. Just initialising the entity will add it to the context, you don't have to manually add it using the Add method.

Comment: @BenCr: The collection obtained from the datacontext.Load / operation.Entities and databound to the view controls is not an ObservableCollection.  It is a view that implements ICollectionView among other things.

Comment: @BenCr: Also, when constructing an instance of MyEntity, I see no change in the DomainContext.HasChanges field.  HasChanges doesn't change to true until I either add the entity to the collection/view or add the entity to a property of an entity that is already in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you bind your control to the `IEnumerable` which is provided by `LoadOperation<TEntity>.Entities`. In that case your binding source is not the `DomainContext.GetEntitySet<MyEntity>()`.

`DomainContext.GetEntitySet<MyEntity>()` holds all your currently tracked instances of `MyEntity`, including the one you add with `.Add()`.

`LoadOperation<TEntity>.Entities` only contains the instances of `MyEntity` that were actually loaded by your last LoadOperation/Query.

You have two options: Either add the new entity to the ItemsSource-collection for your control (I recommend that) or rebuild the collection with the contents of `DomainContext.GetEntitySet<MyEntity>()`. That may contain other elements that you have not cleared out before, though.

Comment: Adding the new entity to the ItemSource of the databound control is not an option, since the new entity is added by the ViewModel and I don't want to make the ViewModel touch the UI controls directly.  I'll try reassigning the ViewModel's MyEntities collection property (which is what the UI databinds to) with the DomainContext.GetEntitySet<..>

Comment: If you create a new instance of an entity, even if you don't physically add it to the entity set, I think the entity set actually tracks it, this means you can create the entity in your view model, add it to your local collection and it'll be in the context for you to submit when you're ready.

Comment: @dthorpe Sorry, I may not have been clear enough. I did assume that your control binds to a collection property of your ViewModel. If it is an `ObservableCollection` and you add the new item to it, then the control should automatically see it.

Comment: @BenCr: No problem getting the new entity sent over to the server with submit changes.  My problem is how to show the new entity on the client before submit changes?

Comment: My point is, if you've got the property i mentioned earlier you can subscribe to the property changed event on it. However, as someone else already suggested, if your property on your view model is an ObservableCollection then your client should already be shown when the new entity is added to the collection as the view will update when the collection changes.